# RxJava Single and Room Error handling Problem

Tags: android, exception, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

I am having this issue regarding empty database return with Room and RxJava Single.
I know that my database is empty, so I am expecting to get an empty return when I trigger

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Times WHERE timestamp = :timestamp")
fun getTimes(timestamp: String): Single<Times>
```

The problem is when I call this function as below

```
timeDao.getTimes("1398332113")
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .doOnError { Log.e("Single", "Returned null") }
       .doOnSuccess { result -> times = result}
       .subscribe()
```

The subscriber is indeed calling `doOnError` method like

> E/Single: Returned null

but still returning an exception and crash

> W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException:
>   Query returned empty result set: SELECT * FROM Times WHERE timestamp =
>   ?

I have seen so many similar questions on StackOverflow, but couldn't find an answer. What am I am doing wrong?

Comment: `doOn...` operators are side effects operators, they aren't subscribers. You should implement `onSuccess` and `onError` in the subscribe method.  You should consider using `Maybe` instead - a Single, as mentioned is success or error, so incases where you have empty results is will error, unless this is desired (IMHO onError should only be for unrecoverable errors, not as a catch all for preventable problems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a solution for your problem. Since version `2.1.0-alpha01` Room supports the `Maybe` return type which is perfect for modelling your problem.

From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html):

The Maybe operates with the following sequential protocol: `onSubscribe (onSuccess | onError | onComplete)?`

When your the item is in the db: `onSuccess` will be called with the data. If the db is empty `onComplete` will be called. `onError` is self explanatory.

Replacing the `Single` with `Maybe` in the Dao class will work.

Further notes:

```
timeDao.getTimes("1398332113")
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .doOnError { Log.e("Single", "Returned null") }
       .doOnSuccess { result -> times = result}
       .subscribe()
```

### doOnError

`doOnError` will execute the the lambda in case of en error, but it will still emit the error down the chain. Your program crashes because it doesn't handle errors (the `subscribe()` is empty).

You could do `subscribe({/* doing nothing for success */}, {e -> Log.e("TAG", "Empty DB")})` to prevent the crash.

### default value

If the goal is to return some default value in case the DB is empty then you will want to use `onErrorReturn` so that the chain continues. Take a look at [this blog post](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/) for more info.

### Null values

The default value can't be null, the Reactive Streams specification (RxJava2 implements it) doesn't support null values.